# Multiple Ubuntu listed in Boot Options menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bios

This question is a follow on from a question I asked recently [unable to boot in to Ubuntu after windows fall creator updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1010127/unable-to-boot-in-to-ubuntu-after-windows-fall-creator-updates)

I am able to boot in to Ubuntu but have noticed that 2 Ubuntu entries are added every time I go in to the BIOS. The second Ubuntu entry with the lowercase 'u' seems to be the only entry that works.

```
Boot Option Menu
 OS boot Manager
 Ubuntu <TOSHIBA MQ01ABF050>
 ubuntu <TOSHIBA MQ01ABF050>
 Ubuntu <TOSHIBA MQ01ABF050>
 Ubuntu <TOSHIBA MQ01ABF050>
 Ubuntu <TOSHIBA MQ01ABF050>
 Ubuntu <TOSHIBA MQ01ABF050>
 Ubuntu <TOSHIBA MQ01ABF050>
 Ubuntu <TOSHIBA MQ01ABF050>
 Boot From EFI File
```

I did read this Q/A [double Ubuntu entry in bios boot options](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840602/double-ubuntu-entry-in-bios-boot-options) but seems a different issue. Assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: I am currently looking at 'deleting a boot option' details from https://linux.die.net/man/8/efibootmgr - and will update on my progress

Comment: Ok so far I have done this on command line: `sudo efibootmgr -v` to print out active and current boot options -then `sudo efibootmgr -b hex# -B` to delete repetitive options that do not work. There were many to delete. I have booted in a few times since and new entries are still being added but at least there is a way to delete even if a temporary fix. It is the file ending in shim64.efi that works not the grub64.efi for me at least.